# Table Collapsible/Expandable + Editable

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have this table https://jsfiddle.net/elalex78/zkxdc1jo/ and I would like it to be collapsible but also editable. If I try both together without luck.
The Table in the link is exactly how should be and the editable javascript is working fine, I just need to know how to collapse the rows, as an example, Item 1 collapse all sub-items 1 inside it, same for item 3.

```
<html>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30px auto 15px;
    grid-template-rows: 40px auto 20px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". title ."
    ". header ."
    ". content ."
    ". footer .";
    grid-gap: 5px;
  }
  .title {
    grid-area: title;
   
  }
  .header {
    grid-area: header;
    place-self: left;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size:50px;

  }
  
  .content {
    grid-area: content;
    display: grid;
  }
  .footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    
  }
  </style>
<!--
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

<!--Script to modify column text live-->   
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#data_table').Tabledit({
        deleteButton: false,
        editButton: false,          
        columns: {
          identifier: [0, 'Item'],                    
          editable: [[1, 'System'],[2, 'Part'], [3, 'Assy'], [4, 'Description'], [5, 'Qty'], [6, 'UOM'], [7, 'Cost']]
        },
        hideIdentifier: false,
        url: ''//'live_edit.php'        
    });
});


</script>
<!--end-->

<!--Script to collapse rows
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
            $('tr.parent')  
                
                .css("cursor", "pointer")  
                .attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")  
                .click(function () {  
                    $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();  
                });  
                
            $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');  
    });  

    
    </script>
<!--end--> 



</head>

<body>
<div class = "grid">
<div class= "title">
<h2> TITLE </h2>
</div>
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
<h2>BOM List</h2>
</div>
<div class = "content">      
<table id="data_table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>  
    <tr>  
        <th>Item</th> 
        <th>Part</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>UOM</th>
        <th>Cost</th> 
        <th>Q/E(Quote/Est)</th> 
        <th>+/- %</th>
        <th>Min</th>
        <th>Max</th> 
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Max</th>
        <th>Min</th>
        <th>Est</th>
        <th>System</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>  
    </thead>   
    <tfoot>  
    <tr>  
        <th>Item</th> 
        <th>Part</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>UOM</th>
        <th>Cost</th> 
        <th>Q/E(Quote/Est)</th> 
        <th>+/- %</th>
        <th>Min</th>
        <th>Max</th> 
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Min</th>
        <th>Max</th>
        <th>Est</th>
        <th>System</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>   
    </tfoot> 
<tbody>  
    <tr class="parent" id="row">  
        <td>1</td>  
        <td>6010230</td>  
        <td>Front Axle</td>  
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>each</td>  
        <td>2000</td>
        <td>E</td>  
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td> 
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td>   
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
        <td>Chassis</td> 
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>1.1</td>   
        <td>1023526</td>    
        <td>Wheel and Tyre</td> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>each</td>  
        <td>2000</td>
        <td>E</td>  
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td> 
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td>   
        <td></td>
        <td>Chassis</td>  
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>1.2</td>   
        <td>1023526</td>    
        <td>Front Brake R</td> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>each</td>  
        <td>2000</td>
        <td>E</td>  
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td> 
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td>   
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
        <td>Chassis</td>    
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td>   
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>1.2.1</td>  
        <td>1024585</td>    
        <td>Chamber R</td> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>each</td>  
        <td>2000</td>
        <td>E</td>  
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td> 
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td>   
        <td></td>
        <td>Chassis</td>    
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td>   
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td></td>  
        <td></td> 
        <td>New Part</td>  
        <td></td>  
        <td></td>  
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>  
        <td></td>
        <td></td>   
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td>   
    </tr> 
    <tr class="parent" id="row">  
        <td>3</td>   
        <td>6010230</td>  
        <td>Front Axle</td>  
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>each</td>  
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>E</td> 
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td> 
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td>   
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
        <td>Chassis</td>  
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>3.1</td>  
        <td>1023526</td>  
        <td>Wheel and Tyre</td> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>each</td>  
        <td>2000</td>
        <td>E</td>  
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td> 
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td>   
        <td></td>
        <td>Chassis</td>    
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>3.2</td>   
        <td>1023526</td>   
        <td>Front Brake R</td> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>each</td>  
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>E</td> 
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td> 
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td>   
        <td></td>
        <td>Chassis</td>    
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td>   
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>3.3</td>  
        <td>1023526</td>    
        <td>Front Brake L</td> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>each</td>  
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>E</td> 
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td> 
        <td>2000</td> 
        <td>1800</td> 
        <td>2200</td>   
        <td></td>
        <td>Chassis</td>     
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td>   
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td></td>  
        <td></td> 
        <td>New Part</td>  
        <td></td>  
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>  
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>  
        <td></td>
        <td></td>   
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td>   
    </tr> 
    <tr class="parent" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td></td>  
        <td>New Assy</td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>  
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>  
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>  
        <td></td>
        <td></td>   
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td>   
    </tr> 
</tbody>  
    </table>
</div>      
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The jquery.tabledit.js file is too big to put here, but it is described in the JSFiddle link :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue creating a expand/collapse part using CSS/JS (without use any library) and the edition as before. See the jsfiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/elalex78/zkxdc1jo/].
Just to don't be only there here the extra code for pure collapse and expand.
HTML (I include class = header inside the row to be collapsed)

```
 <tr class="header expand">  
        <td>1</td>  
        <td>6010230</td>  
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr>    
        <td>1.1</td>   
        <td>1023526</td>     
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td> 
    </tr>  
<tr class="header expand">  
        <td>2</td>  
        <td>6010230</td>  
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr>    
        <td>2.1</td>   
        <td>1023526</td>     
        <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-minus btn btn-danger"></button><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-success"></button></td> 
    </tr>
```

on CSS only pointer and bold stuff

```
tr.header
{
  font-weight : bold;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

and this is the only script

```
//script for collapse/Extend

$('.header').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
});
```

any other CSS table configuration you have will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

Please end the javascript comment.
Change from

```
<!--Script to collapse rows
```

to

```
<!--Script to collapse rows-->
```

Moreover as the id of your both parent rows are same, when you click on one parent row
to collapse or expand both the parents rows become expanded or collapse.
Use different ids for different parent rows and class for child rows like

for Parent rows

```
<tr class="parent" id="row1">

<tr class="parent" id="row2">
```

and for child row

```
<tr class="child-row1" style="display: table-row;">

<tr class="child-row2" style="display: table-row;">
```

Comment: Hello, I did the comment on the proposal, because this function doesn't work together with the Editable script.

Comment: If you see the jsfiddle again, if you remove the comment for the collapse/expand the action will work and the editable will stop working :-(.